# Bash script: referencing a folder path from the script folder, and not from where I run it

Tags: bash, shell, redis

I just bumped into a bug in redis install_server [script](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/utils/install_server.sh)
it has a hardcoded :

```
DEFAULT_CONFIG="../redis.conf"
```

so when running this script not from its own folder (such as ./utils/install_server.sh)
the script fails to find the conf file.

I'm looking for a way to reference the scripts folder without a dependency on where the script is called from.

I looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in) which seems to be the canonical on SO but something is failing for me:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo $DIR
```

and I get:

> ./utils/install_server.sh: 100: ./utils/install_server.sh: Bad substitution
>   /home/myusername/binaries/redis-2.8.3 #where I run the script from..not the folder I need

So I guess I'm doing something wrong, or this isn't the correct answer for me

I know I can add a check if the file exists and a clearer error message to the redis install script, but I rather just make this work.

I'll be glad for ideas, and I'll make a PR to redis to fix this for everyone..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something very similar to what you have posted:

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)"
```

It seems that in your case, something is wrong with BASH_SOURCE.  In my approach, I use $0 which always evaluates to the full pathname used to launch the script.

I'm not sure what the problem with BASH_SOURCE is in your script as what you posted works for me.  Thus I am just offering an alternate approach.

Comment: The problem was not running bash.. but sh.. turned to using your snippets and works for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this with bash (i.e. start the script with `#!/bin/bash` or run it with `bash /path/to/script`), or plain sh (`#!/bin/sh` or `sh /path/to/script`)? Both `BASH_SOURCE` and arrays (`[0]`) are bash extensions, and may not be available in a generic shell. In particular, the "Bad substitution" error is one I've seen from trying to use arrays in a shell that doesn't support them.

Comment: The shebang is ```#!/bin/sh```  and I don't think I'm in liberty to change it. a work around?

Comment: you were right, it turned out the shebang was sh and not bash

Comment: By far the best option is to switch to bash. Using `"$0"` instead of "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" will *sometimes* work, but it depends on exactly how the script is run. See [BashFAQ #28: "How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) for more options, and an explantation of why `$0` is unreliable.

Comment: I checked with the redis guys, no bash there... (the aim for lowest common dependencies)

Comment: In that case your options are pretty limited. You could try the `$0` approach, check whether it finds a redis.conf file, and if not either error out or try the $PWD approach (and if that doesn't find a valid file *then* error out).